# Raspberry Pi with TP-Link TL-WN823N, not disconnecting when hotspot is stopped

Tags: raspberry-pi2

Raspberry Pi 2 (3.18.7-v7+) with Wi-Fi dongle [TP-Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TP-Link) TL-WN823N (8192CU chipset).

I am creating a hotspot on Windows with TP-Link TL-WN823N and configured auto connection on the Raspberry Pi. But when I stop the hotspot, in most of the cases, 'wpa_cli status' shows connected state (`wpa_state=COMPLETED`).

I am unable to detect the source of problem. Please tell me what could be the problem and its possible solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions and this sounds more like you want help configuring your Raspberry PI. For that we have http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ which would be better suited for your question.